# Unable to open some games in Sierra

Tags: macos, error, games

I'm unable to open a couple of games on macOS Sierra. I recently downloaded them, and have never been able to successfully run them. Gatekeeper is already disabled. 
[image: Not runable1]
[image: Not runable2]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to play these games?

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything useful in the log files? Where did you get the games from? Which permissions are set for the application and its content?

Comment: Where are the log files for them located? And it has the default permissions, I haven't changed any of that

Comment: Can you open Terminal, run `ls -ld /where/ever/you/installed/train-valley` and add the results to the question?

Comment: @nohillside https://i.imgur.com/RMEQacv.png here is the screenshot link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like they're Steam games. Try downloading the steam client for macos (Some games can be run without it, but most require the client)